# swift simplifying operations with optional variables

Tags: swift

I'm pretty much a beginner to swift.  I am doing a lot of calculations with values that are intrinsically possibly not there, and I am constantly running into this pattern:

```swift
        var lost : Double? = nil
        if let original = original_value, let current = start_value {
            lost  = original - current
        }
        self.lost = lost
```

which works, but seems ridiculously more complex than it should be.   I know I can go and define a minus between two optional doubles, which I will probably do, but I'm looking for a simplification for the generic case - is there generic way of doing essentially a x?.y operation across *multiple* variables - particularly I want to avoid having to have a variable which you assign twice.   I was hoping you could do something like this:

```swift
    self.lost = if let original = original_value, let current = start_value {original-current}
```

or this:

```swift
    self.lost = (let original = original_value, let current = start_value ) ? original - current : nil
```

but it appears not - but I'm aiming for something like that

Comment: In your first example, the first and last lines seem unnecessary -- you can just assign to `self.lost` inside the `if let` block.

Comment: no I can't - because self.lost is a "let" property - so if I assign it in the if, I get an error saying I need to initialise it.  I can set it to nil in an else block - but that's _even more_ lines of code, and then I have two different lines assigning to a let variable, which feels evil to me for some reason

Comment: in reality - my code is actually self.lost = original_value - start_value, because I just defined a global func - (left: Double?, right: Double?) -> Double? -  so this is more of academic interest - ie is there a better way.

Comment: I don't think the `else` idea is more lines of code, but it is the same number. I didn't realize this was in an initializer, so that fills in a bit of the puzzle. But, if it's in the initializer, I guess I'm a little confused about where `original_value` and `start_value` are coming from (by the way, the convention in Swift is to use camel case). You might want to look into opportunities to use nil coalescing (ie the `??` operator). You can also do a bit like your second option by using a closure -- `self.lost = { /* code in here */ }()`

Comment: that's interesting - the closure idea. I'll play with that ty.

Comment: Does this work?... `self.lost = original_value != nil && start_value != nil ? original_value! - start_value! : nil`

Comment: I don't like that because there's a possible race condition and then crash.

Comment: So your instance of `original_value` and `start_value` can be modified outside of your function? If so, you might be stuck with the long route.

Comment: Actually what I would do is make it longer and clearer. Is the first one nil? Then set the property to nil. Okay, is the second one nil? Then set the property to nil. Okay, if we get here, neither is nil, so force unwrap them, subtract, and set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library doesn't offer a great tool for it. Here's the best I know of, which I think is actually bad.

```swift
lost = original_value.flatMap { original in
  start_value.map { original - $0 }
}
```

I do it like this in my own code:

```swift
lost = Optional(original_value, start_value).map(-)
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Exchange two optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if either optional is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1>(_ optional0: Wrapped0?, _ optional1: Wrapped1?)
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1) {
    self = .init((optional0, optional1))
  }

  /// Exchange two optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if either tuple element is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1>(_ optionals: (Wrapped0?, Wrapped1?))
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1) {
    switch optionals {
    case let (wrapped0?, wrapped1?):
      self = (wrapped0, wrapped1)
    default:
      self = nil
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like that.   As I said - in reality - I just defined a - operator for Double?, which in this case is very clean - but I do like that this will work in every case